# Angularjs Service is not fetching the value in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have an angularjs service which would get the validation result and based on that it will process the page.

```
****************************** My Controller ****************
angular.module('angularApp').controller('angularCtrl', function($scope,validateFactory){

    function getValidationResult(){
        return validateFactory.getValidationResult().then(function(data){
        return data;
    });
  }

     $scope.submission = function submitForm(){
         $scope.form.email.$error.validateEmail = getValidationResult();

        if(validateEmail){
        /* Based on validateEmail value there are some code needs to be executed*/
        }    
     }
});

**************************** My Validation Service ***********************


angular.module('angularApp').factory('validateFactory',function($http,$log){
return {
    getValidationResult : getValidationResult
};

function getValidationResult(){
    return $http.get('data/email-exists.json').then(getValidationCompleted).catch(getValidationFailed);

    function getValidationCompleted(response){
        return response.data;
    }

    function getValidationFailed(error){
        console.log("There is an error in email validation");
    }
};
```

I am not getting the json data for validateEmail variable, Instead I am getting the promise and that is resolved after the if loop. I tried with $q.defer() but getting the same result or I may be missing few lines since I am new to the angular js . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a small detail getValidationResult returns a promise so you need to change:

```
    $scope.form.email.$error.validateEmail = getValidationResult();

    if(validateEmail){
    /* Based on validateEmail value there are some code needs to be executed*/
    }
```

To:

```
    getValidationResult().then(function(data) {
      if(data){
        /* Based on validateEmail value there are some code needs to be executed*/
        $scope.form.email.$error.validateEmail = data;
      } 
    });
```

Comment: No luck. Getting the same